# Calculate Percentage in T SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a Table with the below information.

Name   status
Test1  Running
Test1  Running
Test1  Running
Test1  Running
Test1  Down
Test2  Running
Test2  Down

SQL Query should return me the results like

Name Availaibility
Test1 80%
Test2 50%

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Any code you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    Tests2.Name, 
    (Count(Name)* 100) / (SELECT Count(*) FROM Tests WHERE Tests.Name=Tests2.Name)
FROM Tests AS Tests2
WHERE Status='Running'
GROUP BY Name
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0148c/8/0) is the SQL Fiddle, where I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name,
(sum(case when status='Running' then 1 else 0 end)/sum(case when 1=1 then 1 end))*100 as Availabilty
from table 
group by Name
```